# Pop!_OS - Internet (DNS) broken after attempting to fix captive portal public networks

Tags: networking, wifi, dns

The whole problem started at an airport, where I wasn't able to connect to WiFi on my Pop!_OS laptop. I Googled the problem on another device, and found [this StackOverflow answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826998/cannot-log-in-to-public-open-wifi-connection). Though the first answer (typing in `route` to find the login IP address) worked in the first airport, it didn't on the second, so I tried all of the remaining answers.

**First attempt:**

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

This gave me the message: `resolvconf-pull-resolved.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.`

**Second attempt:**
Edited `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-debian.conf`. This didn't help either. Now, my DNS wouldn't work even when connecting to my iPhone hotspot, and, later, when I got home, to my regular home network! I tried deleting the contents of the file, but no luck.

**Other things I tried:**
- Toggling Privacy/Connectivity Checking
- Making sure my Network Proxy was off
- Toggling WiFi
- Rebooting
- Restarting network service
- Connecting to my iPhone hotspot over Bluetooth
- Connecting to my iPhone hotspot over USB

**Other Random Problems This Caused**

- Running commands with `sudo` threw error `unable to resolve host`

Right now: I'm connected to my home network. I can visit some sites (like `1.1.1.1`) but can't visit sites from the address bar. I'd like to keep the automatic DNS provided by my home network.

Tl;DR: How can I fix my internet? How can I connect to captive portal public wifi in the future?

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`? In modern laptop linux this should normally just contain `nameserver 127.0.1.1` since your DNS is likely managed with `dnsmasq`. You can **temporarily** fix the problem by making it point to some external DNS: `nameserver 208.67.222.222` for OpenDNS.

Comment: @xenoid it says:

```

# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#         DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Comment: @xenoid I think the problem may be that I tried to get `resolvconf` to run my DNS, but it couldn't install correctly since there wasn't internet?

Comment: @xenoid I can confirm that fixes the problem. Is there a more long-term solution?

Comment: Now that you have working internet, try to reinstall/reconfig resolvconf, and if that works reinstate the initial resolv.conf if not done by the reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution!

I edited `/etc/resolv.conf` and replaced:

`nameserver 127.0.0.53` with `nameserver 1.1.1.1`

So I could get internet in the meantime. Then, after seeing [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/134137/1026455), I ran:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf && sudo apt-get install resolvconf`

And rebooted my computer.

Comment: The temporary fix works. But purging and reinstalling `resolvconf` fixed nothing for me.